# How does the Dell U2412M monitor compare to the U2515H with respect to its coating?

Tags: monitors, dell

I am looking for information comparing the coating of the Dell U2412M vs. the more recent Dell U2515H. From the information I could gather so far it seems the Dell U2412M has the same coating as the U2515H which is in both cases an **H3 coating**. On this form and may others I have read that the coating is highly problematic (although not for everyone apparently).

For example this quote:

> In the case of this Dell screen, which uses "Anti Glare H3 Coating" (according to Dell), the coating is very prismatic, or results in visible refraction and even splitting of light into its component colors.<sup>[1](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/31005/does-the-anti-glare-coating-on-the-dell-u2711-interfere-with-its-use-for-photo-e)</sup>

And:

> Avoid anything with anti-glare hard coating. Especially the 3H/H3/whatever that Dell use. It completely and utterly DESTROYS the entire purpose of having an IPS panel; visual quality. <sup>[2](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=377284)</sup>

Prad.de, although a German site, has a **microscope image** for the [U2515H coating](http://www.prad.de/new/monitore/test/2015/test-dell-u2515h-teil6.html#Farbwiedergabe), but I could **not** find one for the U2412M.

I personally own a U2412M and I sometimes get headaches from the monitor so I would like to make sure that if I get the U2515H it does not have the same problems.

Question:

- Can anyone tell how the U2515H compares to the U2412M? In particular with respect to the coating?
- Does anyone have a link to a microscope image of the U2412M's coating?
- Did Dell do any changes to the coating in the recent editions of the Ultra Sharp monitors?

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20150309063845/http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/5222/u2412mgraypixelsmacro.jpg - here you are.

Comment: just to say some words as an owner of 2 U2412Ms: the coating has no effect on viewing angle - but if some light source (sun, bright bulb,..) shines onto its surface, dark areas "wash out". I haven't had this problem with more diffuse lights and it doesn't bother me at all when correcting/viewing my photos for over 3 years now. so the U2412M's coating may not be the best coating in the world, but it's not a catastrophe as some people claim.

Answer (score 1):

I just ordered the 2515 and I will be able to answer that to you when it is shipped.

I have the 2412m and it is one of the worst monitor without a doubt. It is extremely unpleasant to look at because the coating increases the area of the reflection of small light sources and makes a part of the screen completely invisible (lost in light). If I have the window shades open in my room, I am basically blind.

I have 3 other monitors two of which are on the table right now, they are cheap monitors but are better than the more expensive Dell because they don't have that coating.

It's funny how only some reviewers on amazon and forums were bothered by this but not the reviewers (of prad for example), feels like they are paid by Dell to shut up, because the monitor (2412) is a truly bad one.

The reason I bought the 25 is because it was much cheaper than the other ones and because some of youtube videos (Dell UltraSharp U2515H WQHD IPS Monitor Unboxing) have some footage of it in bright light and it looks OK to me, on video that is.

We shall see

Comment: The very point of matte coating is to blur reflections into larger but softer blobs. I, for example, am extremely bothered about your biggest complaint is that matte isn't glare!

Comment: Any updates on that @Sam ?